# Add wikipage on webpart page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: web-part-page

Is possible to add wikipage in webpart page in SharePoint 2013? I want to display wikipage in webpart page .

Comment: Did you try placing `iframe` with your wiki page url in it? Or Else you can try adding `page viewer webpart` in that you can place any page of SharePoint to preview it.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a page in a page might be possible with using a page viewer webpart. Although I'm pretty sure that's not something you want to do.

You might just want to add the webparts on the wiki page, which is perfectly possible.

Comment: Thank You for Quick response .  Actually i have one wiki page with some data . i want to display that wiki page in another page like webpart page. any other possibility rather than page viewer webpart . it displays all page  (ribbon , top navigation bar), we need only content

Comment: If you don't want the default page viewer webpart, you might want to look at making a javascript rest call to extract the content of the wiki page and display it.

An example for an enterprise wiki:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505315/extract-sharepoint-2013-wiki-page-html-source-display-wiki-page-without-master